# Personalizar (estéticamente) histogramas obtenidos de strings en python

Tags: python, string, matplotlib

Tengo un array de 400 elementos con sólo dos valores: hombre y mujer:

```
possible_genders = ['male','female']
gender =  [np.random.choice(possible_genders) for i in range(400)]
```

y el histograma por defecto the matplotlib luce bastante poco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando poner barras gruesas que ocupen casi todo el diagrama y lo mejor que consigo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría conservar el número de elementos que muestra el primer histograma en el eje y (vertical), una pequeña separación entre ambas barras y que las muescas del eje x que representan male y female estén centradas debajo de cada barra.

Toda la información que encuentro está relacionada con ejes numerados, ¿sabéis cómo puedo editar esto?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no lo conoces, puede interesarte investigar la biblioteca [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) que usa por debajo `matplotlib` pero lo configura con unos estilos más "modernos" por defecto. Además te da otras funciones de muy alto nivel para crear autmáticamente gráficos de diferentes tipos que relacionan diferentes columnas de dataframes pandas.

En tu caso se usaría así:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"gender": gender})

# La creación del plot son dos líneas
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.countplot(x="gender", data=df)
```

Y el resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: me encanta! Sí cononzo seaborn pero no esta faceta. Lo he aplicado en mi código y pensaba que el al tener otro df en el mismo archivo podría generar problemas pero veo que no, puedo tener varios df distintos sin que eso sea problemático, ¿verdad?

Comment: @Cacu Puedes tener los dataframes que quieras, mientras no los llames `df` a todos :-) Pero no veo por qué necesitarías un df diferente para seaborn. Le puedes pasar en `data` el df que uses, y en `x` el nombre de la columna a pintar. El resto las ignorará.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes modificar el histograma con los siguientes parámetros

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

possible_genders = ['male','female']
gender =  [np.random.choice(possible_genders) for i in range(400)]

bins=len(possible_genders)
ticks = [i*(1/bins) + (1/bins)/2 for i in range(bins)]

plt.hist(gender, bins=bins, rwidth=0.9, align = 'mid')
plt.xticks(ticks)
plt.show()
```

Detalle:

- Definimos `bins` como el número de categorías, a mostrar, en este caso 2
- Definimos `ticks` como las posiciones de la etiqueta de cada categoria, el ancho de cada barra será `(1/bins)` y por cada una de estas queremos el el `tick` caiga justo en el medio `+ (1/bins)/2`.
- Invocamos `hist()` con el parámetro `rwidth`, para configurar el ancho relativo, ajustado al 90% achicamos las barras para dejar un espacio

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Justo lo que tenía en mente! Gracias :)